# Sorting a vector in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm VERY new to Excel VBA.  I want to write a function that offsets the cells in the current vector (the range selected by the user) by an amount also specified by the user.

The cells must be moved up out of the array by "n", and must then be displayed at the bottom of the same array after the remaining cells have moved up to take the place of the cells shifted up and out of the array.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated, the current code I wrote is not working and I know too little to help myself.

Many thanks!

```
Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Integer)
    'User selects a vector and inputs an integer.
    'The vector must be sorted upwards by the amount equal to the entered integer

    Dim i As Integer, rw As Integer, temp As Variant

    rw = rng.rows.Count

    ReDim b(1 To rw) As Variant
    ReDim temp(1 To n) As Variant

    b = rng
    For i = 1 To n
        temp = b(i)
        'move the data in cells i=1 to n to the temporary array
    Next i

    b(i) = rng.Offset(-n, 0)
    'move the cells in array b up by n

    For i = rw - n To nr
        b(i) = temp
        i = i + 1

        'I'm not sure if this is correct: I want to replace the top shifted cells
        'back into the bottom of array b
     Next i
     ShiftVector4 = b

     'The function must output the newly assembled array b where
     'the top cells that were moved up n-spaces are now wrapped
     'around and are shown at the bottom of the array b
 End Function
```

Comment: Please show some input values and expected output.

Comment: What do you mean by "vector"? A range of cells? if that's the case, please use "Range". It's not clear to me where you want the values  moved. Can you provide a before/after example? Some things that stick out: 1) You don't `Dim` `b`, `rng`, `n` and perhaps some other variables (BTW, naming variables with easier to track names, won't change the performance of your code and help everyone, including you to know what's what.) 2) You don't set `rng` to anything, 3) You don't seem to assign the values to any cells

Comment: Input values in a 1 dimensional array:
1
hi
5
hey
3
9
7
yo
2
Output values (what I'm trying to achieve) if I move all the cells up by 3:
hey
3
9
7
yo
2
1
hi
5

Comment: Apologies @cybernetic.nomad for using wrong way to name the variables, thanks for comments will keep them in mind, here is input values and expected output:                                   
Input values in a 1 dimensional array:
1,
hi,
5,
hey,
3,
9,
7,
yo,
2,
Output values (what I'm trying to achieve) if I move all the cells up by 3:
hey
3,
9,
7,
yo,
2,
1,
hi,
5,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub Tester()
    ShiftUp Range("B4:C13"), 3
End Sub


Sub ShiftUp(rng As Range, numRows As Long)
    Dim tmp
    With rng
        tmp = .Rows(1).Resize(numRows).Value
        .Rows(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - numRows).Value = _
          .Rows(numRows + 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - numRows).Value
        .Rows((.Rows.Count - numRows) + 1).Resize(numRows).Value = tmp
    End With
End Sub
```

As a UDF:

```
Function ShiftUp(rng As Range, numRows As Long)
    Dim d, dOut, r As Long, c As Long, rMod As Long, rTot As Long
    Dim break As Long
    d = rng.Value
    dOut = rng.Value 'as a shortcut to creating an empty array....
    rTot = UBound(d, 1)
    break = rTot - numRows
    For r = 1 To rTot
        For c = 1 To UBound(d, 2)
            'figure out which input row to use...
            rMod = IIf(r <= break, r + numRows, -(break - r))
            dOut(r, c) = d(rMod, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    ShiftUp = dOut
End Function
```

Note this is an array formula, so you will need to select a range the same size as the input range and enter the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: My sincere thanks @TimWilliams, you have made my life a lot easier! Your code works flawlessly :)

Comment: How would you go about converting your subroutine into a function?

Comment: With what inputs and what outputs?

Comment: Inputs will be user selecting the rng(for example the array I listed that includes both strings and integers) and specifying numRows by whch the array cells must be moved up.  Then output this new array to another place on the spreadsheet without changing the contents/ position of the intial array. Does what I'm trying to say make sense? :)

Comment: Do you mean as a UDF to be used in a worksheet formula?

Comment: Yes...so the user will type =ShiftUp(A1:A9,3) into a cell on the worksheet, select the specified range and specify the number that the cells need to be moved up by

Comment: You are my hero :) Thank you so much for your kind assistance and patience, I really appreciate it!